# Importing git bundle into gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-omnibus, git-bundle

I've created a git bundle out of my repo and I'm trying to import it to gitlab.  I've tried the API via curl command which gives me the error `Error importing repository  into root/api-project - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - [FILTERED]` and I've tried using the gitlab-rake and when I add --trace the only output is

```
** Invoke gitlab:import:repos (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute gitlab:import:repos
```

**Is there a better way to import a git bundle (.bundle file) into gitlab? And if not then what can I do to fix the import or at least get a better output log from the gitlab-rake command?**

Answer (score 0):

2020: Instead of using a git bundle, you could follow "[Import your project from GitHub to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html)" and use the [GitHub importer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/github_importer.html) (GitLab 10.2 and more)

> Using the importer, you can import your GitHub repositories to GitLab.com or to your self-managed GitLab instance.
>
> References to pull requests and issues are preserved (GitLab.com & 8.7+), and each imported repository maintains visibility level unless that [visibility level is restricted](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects), in which case it defaults to the default project visibility.

---

See [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#speed-up-imports-from-github-using-multiple-access-tokens) (July 2023)

> ### Speed up imports from GitHub using multiple access tokens
>
> By default, the GitHub importer uses a single access token when importing projects from GitHub to GitLab. An access token for a user account is typically rate limited to
> 5000 requests per hour. This can significantly reduce the speed of the importer when:
>
> - Importing multiple small to medium sized projects.
> - Importing a single massive project with a lot of data.
>
> With this release, you can pass a list of access tokens to the GitHub importer API so that the API can rotate through them when rate limited.
> When using multiple access tokens:
>
> - The tokens cannot be from the same account because they would all share one rate limit.
> - Tokens must have the same permissions and sufficient privileges to the repositories to import.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/import.html#import-repository-from-github) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337232).